# assigning binary to vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, binary

I am trying to convert a number to network and then to put the result in a vector in

```
std::vector<char> vctData;  
u_long lnum = 145;  
lnum = htonl(lnum);  
//This line should put lnum at the beginning of vector in the first 4 bytes  
vctData.insert(vctData.begin(), ???, ???);
```

what to do ???

Thanks

Comment: std::vector needs a template parameter to be passed.

Comment: Next time, click on the {} to format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vctData;
u_long lnum = 145;
lnum = htonl(lnum);
vctData.insert(vctData.begin(), (unsigned char *) &lnum, (unsigned char *) (&lnum + 1));
```

This takes the individual bytes of lnum and puts them one by one into vctData.

Comment: Even better, use the appropriate `std::vector` constructor directly: `std:vector<unsigned char> vctData((unsigned char *)&lnum, (unsigned char *)(&lnum + 1));`.

Comment: @Frerich: Using the constructor is NOT better if the goal is to assemble a lot of values into a packet, with control over byte order and padding.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After knowing, you need to add `lnum` to a vector of char, then do this:

```
std::vector<char> vctData; //note: mention the type argument!
u_long lnum = 145;  
lnum = htonl(lnum);  

//inserts in the beginning!
vctData.insert(vctData.begin(),(char*)&lnum, (char*)&lum + sizeof(u_long));
```

Try this. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I need to add it in vector of char